# Avoid code-chunks from breaking in Knitr? ( preferably using a chunk option )

Tags: r, pdf, break, knitr, floating

Using knitr to create a pdf, codechunks break according to page breaks. Usually this is exactly what I want, but in some cases I would like to be able to avoid this. E.g. by making a code-chunk jump to the next page if it does not fit the current page. I would prefer if this could be done in a chunk option, I.E not using eg. \newpage etc.

The following is an example of a code-chunk that breaks. How do I avoid this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3] \textbf{The following chunk will break. How do I avoid this breaking? }



<<echo=TRUE>>=

(iris)[1:20,]

@



\end{document}
```

Comment: It goes without saying, but I'll say it anyway. Have you tried adding `\newpage` or `\clearpage` in front of the chunk? It would be nice if this was done automatically (controlled through chunk options), though.

Comment: Thanks. I will rephrase the question.

Comment: can you embed the chunk into a floating environment such as `\begin{figure}[!Htbp]...\end{figure}{}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I left an empty environment `knitrout` in the `knitr` design for such purposes. You can redefine this environment to achieve what you want. There are many LaTeX environments that are non-breakable, such as a `figure` environment. Below I use the `minipage` environment as an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewenvironment{knitrout}{\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}}{\end{minipage}}
% alternatively, you can use `figure`
% \renewenvironment{knitrout}{\begin{figure}}{\end{figure}}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\caption{One figure.}
\end{figure}

% placeholder
\framebox{\begin{minipage}[t][0.3\paperheight]{1\columnwidth}%
nothing
\end{minipage}}

<<echo=TRUE>>=
(iris)[1:20,]
@

\begin{figure}
\caption{Another one.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```